# Entity using entity manager , how good is this design?

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, jpa-2.0

I'm evaluating this design that allow entity to have acces to an entity manager .

**Book Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Long isbn;
    private String nom;

     public void save() {
        System.out.println("OWN PERSIST !");
      **ThreadLocalEntityManager.em().persist(this);**
    }
}
```

**BookService:**

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(EntityManagerInjector.class)

public class BookService {
       public void create()
       {
         Book b=new Book(1,2,"3");
         b.save();
       }
}
```

**EntityManagerInjector**

```
public class EntityManagerInjector implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object associate(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        ThreadLocalEntityManager.associateWithThread(em); //statically imported method
        try {
            return ic.proceed();
        } finally {
            ThreadLocalEntityManager.cleanupThread();
        }
    }
}
```

**ThreadLocalEntityManager**

```
public class ThreadLocalEntityManager {

    private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> THREAD_WITH_EM = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

    private ThreadLocalEntityManager() {
    }

    public static void associateWithThread(EntityManager em) {
        THREAD_WITH_EM.set(em);
    }

    public static EntityManager em() {
        System.out.println("gettint entitymanger from thread:"+THREAD_WITH_EM.toString());
        System.out.println("entitymanger id:"+THREAD_WITH_EM.get().toString());
        return THREAD_WITH_EM.get();
    }

    public static void cleanupThread() {
        THREAD_WITH_EM.remove();
    }
}
```

I have some questions:

1. Is this a good design to avoid using crud service (create,delete,findXX)?
2. Can this desing create any kind of runtime execution problms in the
   container ?
3. Is changing `book.save()` declaration to static a good way to simplify the acces to "Persistence operations" (avoid new `Book().find(id)"` ?

Thanks .
ps1: I'm using `JPA 2`, `Ejb 3.1` and  Glassfish 3.1.2

ps2: I found this desing in Real World Java EE Patterns Rethinking Best Practices (Adam Bien)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue against this design.

1. Most App Server don't like it when you tinker with the Thread

   App Server do a lot of near magic thread management for processing requests and it is strongly recommended that you not even create threads in JavaEE.
2. EntityManagers are transitory things

   An EM should really only live as a long as a transaction lasts.  In this instance, it looks like the EM could be passed into different applications running in the same container.  Which could make debugging a real joy.

   Imagine if you called a different EJB from BookService, it would set the EM to be the other EJB's EM.  This would be a huge problem if you ever have two persistence units.
3. Not open to extension

   Any new EJBs in this system would have to know about this interesting way of handling EMs.  This is ok if you're the one writing them but what about externally provided EJBs?
4. Lack of Cohesion

   The EJB is where the transaction is controlled/defined.  Why would we want to push out the interface to the JPA bean?  `save()` will only work inside this very specific framework and is going to be a 100% pain in the ass to unit test.

   Think if you want to re-use this bean for doing something which needs XML serialization like WebServices.  Now `save()` doesn't work right.  The persistence engine can already deal with beans generically, don't write another layer on top of it to strip that out.